# mysql вставить Id связанных таблиц

Tags: c#, mysql

3 таблицы связанный между собой под общее поле ID, при вставке данных в таблицу еще нужно вставить соответствующую ID главной таблицы(тоесть в главной таблице заполнен перечень,  при вставке нужно определить какому перечиню принадлежит вставляемая запись) дайте пожалуйста совет как это сделать, для ясности вложил таблицы mysql связами.
запрос вставки который вообще не работает.
`` query = "INSERT INTO `dslam` (`dslam`, `ip`, `sats_id`, WHERE `sats_id` SELECT `id`  FROM `sum`) VALUES('@dslam', '@ip', '@sats_id')"; ``
в эту таблицу пытаюсь вставить ID следующей таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE `dslam` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dslam` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`ip` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`sats_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `sats_id` (`sats_id`),
 KEY `id` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `dslamForSats` FOREIGN KEY (`sats_id`) REFERENCES `sum` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

главная таблица. данные этой таблицы вытащил в combobox ValueMember.

```
  CREATE TABLE `sum` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
кнопка ADD
private void AddDslambutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {

            MySqlCommand commandSelect = new MySqlCommand("Select ip from dslam where ip=@ip AND dslam=@dslam", con);
            commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", textBox1.Text);
            commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dslam", comboBox2.Text);
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            con.Open();
            reader = commandSelect.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("такой запись уже существует!");
                con.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                con.Close();
                query = "INSERT INTO dslam (dslam, ip, id SELECT FROM sum, WHERE sats_id =id) VALUES (@dslam, @ip, @sats_id)";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@dslam", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = comboBox2.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ip", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = textBox1.Text;
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@sats_id", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = SelectSatsDslam.Text;
                
                con.Open();
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Added!");
                }

                con.Close();
                spisokDWG2();
            }
        }
    }
```

вывод значения ID в combobox

```
void SelectSatsForDslam()
    {
        query = "Select name from sum";
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        con.Open();
        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dset, "name");
        SelectSatsDslam.DisplayMember = "name";
        SelectSatsDslam.ValueMember = "name";
        SelectSatsDslam.DataSource = dset.Tables["name"];
        con.Close();
        if (SelectSatsDslam.Items.Count > 1)
        {
            SelectSatsDslam.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }
    }
```

Comment: никто не подскажет как сделать правильный запрос ?

Comment: параметры @dslam, @ip, @sats_id на момент вставки тебе известны? если да, то простой запрос: INSERT INTO `dslam` (`dslam`, `ip`, `sats_id`) VALUES(@dslam, @ip, @sats_id)

Comment: наконец-то кто то откликнулся =) , параметры dslam, ip пользователь вводит через Textobx (тоесть принимает значения текстбоксов). а вот sats_id  должен получать из другой таблицы ( таблицы sum ) . все значение таблицы sum вывел в combobox.

Comment: через phpmyadmin все добавляется , тоесть все ID значения таблицы sum можно выбирать и добавить с вводимыми данными. а как это сделать программой (c#) не знаю...

Comment: параметр sats_id вы должны получить из вашего комбобокса, раз , как я понимаю, пользователь вводит требуемое значение на некой форме в интерфейсе. SQL к этому никакого отношения не имеет. Уточните вашу проблему, на каком языке разработана ваша программа.

Comment: у вас Windows Forms? добавьте код вашей формы ввода в вопрос.

Comment: да , winforms , щас добавляю весь код вставки

Comment: добавил,  посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте вот так:

```cs
void SelectSatsForDslam()
{
    //conn - должен быть раннее объявлен и иницирован
    string query = "select id, name from sum";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable table = new DataTable("myTable");
    da.Fill(table);
    
    SelectSatsDslam.DataSource = da;
    SelectSatsDslam.DisplayMember = "name";
    SelectSatsDslam.ValueMember = "id";
    con.Close();
    if (SelectSatsDslam.Items.Count > 1)
    {
        SelectSatsDslam.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

получение выбранного значения из комбобокса (перед выполнением запроса на обновление/добавление):

```cs
int id = Convert.ToInt32(SelectSatsDslam.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: почему-то не выводит

Comment: если в DataSource передать саму таблицу не работает , если передать только одно поле работает...

Comment: тут дело не в c# , а самом mysql